# Spring Boot JMS only transactions support

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-transactions, spring-jms

I'm writing a service and I need to use transactions for JDBC & JMS but not distributed.Is it possible use Spring @Transactional annotation on JMS Listener method for a JMS only Transacion using Bitronix or Atomikos since these 2 are also autoconfigured by Spring ?

As far as I know, when I add this dependency, my dataBase transaction also became XA.

What are my options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see the [boot documentation about `Mixing XA and non-XA JMS connections`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_mixing_xa_and_non_xa_jms_connections).

Comment: OK, but I then I need to set `spring.datasource.xa.dataSourceClassName=` property, and , I'm usign MSSQL DB, it gives error:`javax.transaction.xa.XAException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Could not find stored procedure 'master..xp_sqljdbc_xa_recover` because Db is not configured for XA. what I want is to enable 2 transaction managers, 1 for JMS, 1 for JDBC. I can type the name of the transaction manager if necessary. I'm just curious if it's possible by default or after adding Bitronix or Atomikos, I assume it's necessary, what can I do minimally to achieve this ?

Comment: Or, do I need this in the first place ? If I get exception, even without transaction, what happends on JMS side ? Does it retry the message, I'm using persistent queues ?

Comment: You can just use local transactions (acknowledge="transacted") on the inbound listener container and it will just use a local JMS transaction (no `@Transactional` or transaction manager needed).

Comment: JMSListener doesn't have acknowledge="transected" property. also, what is difference between sessionAcknowledgeModeName and sessionTransacted ? I believe it'd  be bice to add these parameters to JMSProperties so spring-boot can configure them automatically.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't realize you were using an annotation based listener; the xml parser coerces `transacted` ackmode to `setSessionTransacted()`. Looks like you might need a custom [listener container factory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-annotated) to set that; subclass the default factory and override `initializeContainer`; I am not sure why it's not exposed by default; I'll ask the devs.

Comment: I already opened a request ob github for this. [github-request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3390)

Comment: My mistake, the default factory *does* have `setSessionTransacted` so no need for a subclass; but you do need to customize the factory (until/unless they are added to boot).